# Add a class to an element depending on the selected options in select2 jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The form contains 2 drop-down lists. I would like to add a class to the second drop-down list if certain elements are selected in the first one.

The form in html is something like this (the form itself works correctly):

```
<form class="searchandfilter">
    <ul>
        <li class="sf-type">
            <label>
                <select>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" value="">- all -</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-1" value="item1">item1</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-2" value="item2">item2</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-3" value="item3">item3</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-4 sf-option-active" selected="selected" value="item4">item4</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </li>

        <li class="sf-status">
            <label>
                <select>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" value="">- all -</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-1" value="item1">item1</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-2" value="item2">item2</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-3" value="item3">item3</option>
                    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-4" value="item4">item4</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

For example, the user selects in the field `.sf-field-taxonomy-type` option value `item4`. Then a class `active` is added to the `.sf-field-taxonomy-status` field.

I try something like this, but the class is not added(

```
$('.sf-type select').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === 'item4') {
        $('.searchandfilter').find('.sf-status').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of changes to your code and got it to work. First of all, I like to bind handlers to DOM objects with `.on()` method. In my experience this works better than the shorthands, like `click()` etc.
Second, since you don't have (at least in the snippet) other elements with class `sf-status` except the `<li>`, you can shorten the jQuery selector to `$('.sf-status')`. Ofcourse you can also use ID if you have others. Anyhow, the code below should work:

```
$('.sf-type select').on('change',function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === 'item4') {
        $('.sf-status').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

This does work with the original `$('.searchandfilter').find('.sf-status').addClass('active');` also.